# Python qgis script

Tags: pyqgis, file-path

[image]

How to get the path of points?

Because I want to open it using this code:

```
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(path,"YXC","ogr")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the name of your layer parameter (in your case, `points`):

```
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(points, "YXC", "ogr")
```